# C# calling parent property while the child property is being called

Tags: c#, inheritance

I wanna see if there is anyway that when the child property method is being called, it will call the parent property as well.
Note that the child is generated by a code generator from edmx.  So I can't change anything except adding a partial class for the child class.  (It might be too trouble to change the generator.)

The situation I am having : 
I have a class "MyClass" that is automatically generated from the database.  I can't change anything on it except adding a partial class or change the code generator.

Now, I need to "do something" whenever the property Name is being called.  I am thinking if I can put a parent there and make it call the parent to do "something" when the child property is "Name" is being called.

What I want :

```
public class ClassBase
{
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            CallMethod();
            return Name;
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : ClassBase 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Name; < -- this will call the parent as well.
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear enough what you're asking.  Also note that as your property is not marked `virtual`, it is not actually inherited, but masking the parent.  Turn on compiler warnings as errors to avoid this gotcha!  With that, it sounds like what you want is `base`.  Look it up.

Comment: Your parent class's `get` definition recursively calls itself, thus causing a Stack Overflow Exception.

Comment: If the child class should just use the base class's definition of `Name`, why not just not add it to the child class at all?  Just remove the definition entirely and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have elaborate the question.

Comment: Is "ClassBase" `partial` by any chance (similar to ASP.Net page class)? Is `CallMethod` virtual? (I've put couple optin in my answer, but most likely you are out of luck if you can't change base class and it does not have extensibility points for the property).

Comment: I can add partial for child.  Parent can change anyway we want.  Just can't touch the original child class and the way to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really related but since you're not strictly using automatic properties in ClassBase, you should create a private string variable for `Name`. Something like `_name` or whatever your internal coding standards dictate.

```
public class ClassBase
{
  private string _name;
  public virtual string Name 
  { 
    get 
    { 
      CallMethod();
      return _name;
    }
    set
    {
      _name = value;
    }
  }
}


public class MyClass : ClassBase 
{
  //Pretty pointless really since you're not doing anything with MyClass.Name.
  public new string Name
  {
    get
    {
      return base.Name;
    }
    set
    {
      base.Name = value;
    }
}


MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Name; <-- this will call the parent as well.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the restriction is , I can't change the child class.

Comment: @KennethLam If you can't change the child class, it's not really going to work, because you're doing the inheritance correctly, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "can't change base class" comment there is pretty much nothing you can do to make some code to be executed instead/before/after base class because your property/method will not be called when your new class used as base class (see sample in details part).

Potential solution : if you need to extend specially designed `parital` class's and it provides extension poinst like `CallMethod` is marked as  [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) - it is expected for implemnting portion of the class to implement it :

```
partial public class ClassBase
{
    partial void CallMethod();
    public string Name {get {CallMethod(); return "";}}
}


// in generated portion of "ClassBase"
partial public class ClassBase
{
    partial void CallMethod() { /* do something here */ }
}
```

**Answer** to exact "how to call base class property" is to use `base`, but hiding property/method this way is confusing (see below):

```
new public string Name { get { return base.Name;} }
```

Note that you can't use automatic property in derived class case as you explicitly want some additional code to be executed. If you need `set` in derived class you need own backing field like:

```
private string derivedName;
new public string Name { 
   get { return base.Name + derivedName;} 
   set { derivedName = value;}
}
```

**Details:**

As said in comments hiding base class' properties/methods leads to very confusing behavior. For you case (slightly updated base class with baking field as original sample had infinite recursion):

```
public class ClassBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            CallMethod();
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to hide `Name` property in derived class:

```
public class MyClass : ClassBase 
{
    // notice "new" to show comiler you know what you doing
    // otherwise you'll get warning (but behavior will be the same)
    new public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The issue with hiding is that base class' method is still easily callable and likely be called by mistake if using derived class as base class:

```
MyClass myDerved = new MyClass();
ClassBase myDervedAsBase = myDerved;
var name = myDerived.Name; // calls MyClass.Name
var name = myDerivedAsBase.Name; // calls ClassBase.Name
```

This can be solved by making base class' method/property `virtual` - but it requires change in base class:

```
public class ClassBase
{
    virtual public string Name { get {... } }
}

public class MyClass : ClassBase 
{
    override public string Name { get { ... } }
}
```

If you need to call base class' method/property from derived class use`base.MethodName()` like:

```
    override public string Name { get 
      {
          // do some new stuff here
          var baseName = base.Name;
          // maybe even change result
          return baseName;
      }
    }
```

If you expect most derived classes to need such behavior it could be better to design base class explicitly to enforce such behavior. For example you can have property to call virtual method before/after computing the value to return like:

```
public class ClassBase
{
    virtual protected string AboutToReturnName(string result) 
    {
       return name;    
    }
    public string Name 
    { 
      get 
      {
        var result = "MyName";
        return AboutToReturnName(result);
      }
    }
}
```

More ideas:

- Alternative to `virtual` is `partial` methods which works when instead of deriving class is combined from many "partial" parts like ASP.Net pages - see [Partial Classes and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)
- If you need notifications around change of property - consider implementing `INotifyPropertyChange`
- if you need to know when properties/method are called in general - consider using interfaces and automatically generate wrapper classes that have pre/post callback. I.e. mocking frameworks (like EasyMoq or RhinoMock) and DI containers (like Unity) provide and use such functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your lengthy reply.  All the solution you provided required a change on the child class.  Even InotifyPropertyChange require to change the Set Accessor in order to make it work.

Comment: @KennethLam - yes, unless base class designed to allow you what you trying to achieve you are basically out of luck. Note that for testing you may use [Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) to intercept property/method calls...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it without modifying the code generator. The modification would have to generate a call `base.Name`.

Comment: I can't really find a good article on how to modify it.  Do you know any?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but search the web. I'm sure you can modify the T4 template it uses.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the property in your subclass with the new operator.

```
public class MyClass : ClassBase 
{
    public new string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's what he's doing now, since it's not marked as `override`, this is just making it explicit.  This doesn't change the code in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the restriction is , I can't change the child class.  Except adding a partial